# Bluetooth heartrate monitor byte decoding

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

## Problem :

I am having trouble with understanding the returned data of the [BLE Heart Rate Characteristic](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml)(service `180d`, characteristic `2a37`).

According to the specification there will be either 6 or 7 bytes of data (when base64-decoded), i fully understand how to deal with it when this is the case.

But sometimes it won't return 6 or 7 bytes but 8 and more rarely 4 bytes, i have no idea why there are more/less bytes and what the meaning of the added bytes is or which bytes are left out.

I could skip all the cases where there are not 6 or 7 bytes but i want to fully understand this.

I am *certain* that the converting the base64-encoded to byte-array is done correctly, i made a function for it **and** checked it using manual base64-decode combined with `charCodeAt(index)` **and** truly manually checked it using good ol' pencil, paper and brain (not necessarily in that order).

#### TL;DR :

BLE Heart Rate (`180d`,`2a37`) sometimes does not return the expected amount of bytes (4 and 8 when it should be either 6 or 7 bytes).
**What exactly happened and why?**

### Example :

```
// Example results in byte-array's
["00010110", "01110111", "00000100", "00000010"] // unexpected 4 byte
["00010110", "01111000", "11111111", "00000001", "11111111", "00000001", "00001100", "00000001"] // unexpected 8 byte
["00010110", "01110111", "00001000", "00000010", "00001000", "00000010"] // normal 6 byte

// Example results in hex-array's (easier to read on small screens)
["0x16","0x77","0x04","0x02"] // unexpected 4 byte
["0x16","0x78","0xFF","0x01","0xFF","0x01","0x0C","0x01"] // unexpected 8 byte
["0x16","0x77","0x08","0x02","0x08","0x02"] // normal 6 byte
```

#### Byte Explanation :

1. Flags. The first bit (most right) is on if the heart rate is in 16 bit format (i only got 8 bit).
2. heartrate, if the heart rate is in 16 bit format there will be 2 bytes here
3. energy expended
4. energy expended
5. rr interval
6. rr interval

Comment: Of course it could be [F][C1][C4][C4] in the 4 byte case but shouldn't that be in the documentation if that's the case? But this does not explain the 8 byte scenario...

Comment: What is the system?  OS hardware setup etc.  Where is the code that interacts with the system whatever it is, that is the most likely cause of the trouble...

Comment: @lfor i am using randdusings ble plugin in a cordova app. The plugin contains the code (src/android/*.java or www/*.js) and can be easily found by googling 'cordova-plugin-bluetooth'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Energy expenditure is optional check the bit 3 of the flags in your sample data case it is not present.  There are a variable number of rr intervals.  with 4 bytes you have just 1 with 6 bytes you have 2 and with 8 bytes you have 3 you could in theory get 10 and 4.

You should decode the bytes using the flags then if rr's are present the number of bytes left / 2 is the number of rr's you have.

See the [XML-Definition](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml) file for more details.

Comment: according to the specification the energy expended is of size `uint16` which means 2 bytes. for the rest it's not really clear what you are saying...

Comment: yes it's 2 bytes but it's optional.  if bit 3 of the flags is not set then you don't get those two bytes and everything else moves up.  You get a variable number of rr entries of 2 bytes each.  You basically look at how many bytes you have left after decoding the initial stuff and that tells you how many rr's you will have.